# Gnosis safe owners addresses on contract's code

Tags: gnosis-safe

where on my deployed gnosis contract I can see that my assigned owner are really there?
My fear is that maybe there are some additional owners set in there.
I would like to know where on my deployed code I can find the list of assigned owners.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's an article on how to [verify Safe creation](https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/4774916-verify-safe-creation)

Comment: I think that article is outdated, "contract creation code" is different here, maybe I'm at a newer version?

Comment: Yes, it's outdated for that part. you can compare it with https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xca669e8fCB5c0B6D7A17C5Be2B0513cE529De8ea#code

Comment: well It still don't match, rinkeby? mine is on mainnet

Comment: if you provide more details (safe address, how you deployed it, etc.) we can look into it

Comment: proxy codes are the same on all networks